# Why does this grounding bar have three different kinds of screws?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I bought a Murray load center for use as a subpanel. Why do the large terminals in the grounding bar have three different kinds of screws?

Which of them should I be using for the feeder (4-gauge aluminum)

[image: Grounding bar]

The instructions have no guidance on the different screws in the large terminals:

[image: Instructions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you notice, it has 15 small openings and 3 large.  The others are for securing tbe buss to the panel.
2. <strike>Also, you'll need a lug adapter to secure the #4 grounding conductor as per the panels specifications only up to #6 will fit in the three larger openings.</strike>

Edit to (2): I believe anything over #4 will need a lug adapter.

Comment: It says that 1/0 through 6 gauge will fit in the large terminals.

Comment: Thanks.  I believe anything over #4 will need an adapter.

Comment: Concur on the two socket-head cap screws being for mounting (and bus-case bonding).  But where are you getting #4?  I am also getting 1/0, because I zoomed in on the edge of the aluminum bus bar which is stamped `NISCO N8108 1/0-14` every couple of inches.  Torque instructions seem to affirm that, I'd use 45 in.lb.

Comment: @Harper You know I think I confused #4 with 1/0... My bad